# The proper way to add elements in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How would one add an element in **ReactJS**? If I want to add a **table row** on a **button click**, is it bad practice to use `appendChild()`?

Comment: When using react: Yes it is. Use states in a React component

Comment: It just use in some necessary situation. Normally, you should control it in your component, like a loop to render table when state change or something like that

Comment: @dungtranhcmus you should **NEVER** use direct DOM manipulation methods in a ReactJS app, it goes against the entire purpose of ReactJS. If you ever find it "necessary", then you need to rethink what you're trying to accomplish and solve it in the correct "React Way"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is it bad practice to use the appendChild()

**YES**, this goes against the entire purpose of ReactJS

Your ReactJS app should render the UI based on data, in which case, you'll never have to use direct DOM manipulation, especially since any changes you make will be wiped out in the next ReactJS render.

The way ReactJS works is that it creates a Virtual DOM and compares changes against the previous version of the Virtual DOM. If there are changes, it will update the real DOM that the user sees. This is why you shouldn't use functions like `appendChild` and `innerHTML`, or other DOM manipulation methods, because ReactJS won't care what you manually did in the real DOM, and will wipe it out.

Here's a basic runnable example that has a table with two people, and a button that adds another person to the state, which causes the table to re-render and add another `tr`

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableData: [
        { name: 'John', age: 25 },
        { name: 'Peter', age: 43 }
      ]
    };
    this.renderTableRows = this.renderTableRows.bind(this)
    this.addPerson = this.addPerson.bind(this)
  }
  addPerson() {
    const newPerson = { name: 'Mary', age: 38 }
    const tableData = [
      ...this.state.tableData,
      newPerson
    ]
    this.setState({tableData});
  }
  renderTableRows() {
    const { tableData } = this.state
    if (!tableData) return null;
    let result = [];
    tableData.forEach(person => {
      result.push(
        <tr>
          <td>{person.name}</td>
          <td>{person.age}</td>
        </tr>
      )
    });
    return result;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
          </tr>
          {this.renderTableRows()}
        </table>
        <button onClick={this.addPerson}>Add Person</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

#### Documentation

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model

Comment: Thank you. This really helped!

Comment: Just wanted to come back a little while later and let you know that this helped me understand state and props so much more. I now use it for pretty much everything like I should when rendering dynamic data. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Add your data in an array of objects in the state, where one object is equal to one row of your table.
Then you could add one row like this:

```
......
this.state = { 
   ArrayData: [],
   newRowValueObject: {}
}
....

<Button onClick={()=>[...this.state.ArrayData, newRowValueObject]}> <Button/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise making the table dynamic for the data that you have, and setting the data to the state. When you click, you can update state (by adding the new row's data), which will re-render the table with the new row of added data.